# Simple ray collision library (bonus if it loads 3ds and b3d)

Tags: c++, 3d, collision-detection

I've spent quite some time searching a simple / fast c++ library (Win / Linux) that can answer the two questions 'does this ray crosses any of the triangles?' or 'where is the first intersection, if there are any?'.

It's for my little game I'm writing and will be used to see if a NPC can see a player and also to check if a player can fall all the way to the ground (or not).
The triangles will not move (well, if you can flag a triangle group 'on' / 'off' that would be nice).

I actually found some libraries but only non-continued (or it seems) like OZCollide for example.
Of course there are all those new shiny Physics engines out there but I don't need 99% of what they offer.

A bonus would be if the library can load .3ds an .b3d files and even better if it can be used in a multi threaded environment (creating several instances of the search data).

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there seems to be no 'simple & small' library / code out there so I guess the answer might be 'roll your own'.
That is what I did anyway:
a tool that uses Irrlicht to load up my (static) geometry and then save off all (triangle/vertex) data to a file, just 9 floats for each triangle.
Then a collision library that loads up the data into an octree and the c2005 triangle / ray intersection test and it works OK.

Answer (score 5):

Bullet Physics (http://bulletphysics.org/) is a physics library, but it's built in several layers.
Because of this it can be used as just a collision library which is quite efficient at casting rays through a scene.
(You wouldn't be using or be bothered by any of its physics features)

It's available on Windows and Linux, but also on several more platforms and even on game consoles.
The library is proven and used professionally by various game developers.

It does not directly support .3ds files, but it does has a pipeline for getting geometry from various 3D modelling applications converted to the right format Bullet understands.

It might feel overkill to use it because it's a physics library. But that is actually the reason you should be using it.
A physics library is highly reliant on a good collision library, which actually forces the collision library to be of high quality and offer excellent performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I even checked it out but it really is Big. Just so you don't think I don't care, my client already has those functions through Irrlicht (I needed to create a bugfix/Patch to make it work in realtime though) so if I "have to" (ie. I don't find any small simple & fast library) I'll rip out the code from Irrlicht and integrate it into my server code but I hoped not to need that / find a cleaner solution :-)